# I want to implement Like/Dislike functionality without user login using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller, facebook-like

I have to implement like/dislike functionality in my project but when I refresh the page the user can again like that post that is already liked by that user.

To maintain the state of the user I have taken the IpAddress of the user in DB.

I want if the user already likes the post then the user should not be able to like again that particular post.

**Here is my controller code.**

```
    public function save_likedislike(Request $request) {
        $data=new Like_Dislike; 
        $data->fkTeamId= Request::post('post');
        $ipAdd = Request::ip();
        $data->varIpAddress = $ipAdd;

        if(Request::post('type') == 'like'){
            $data->intLike=1;
        } else {
            $data->intDislike=1;
        }
      
        $data->save();
        return response()->json([
            'bool'=>true
        ]);
        return $records;
    }
```

Here are the HTML fields like buttons and incrementing the count using jquery ajax code.

```
    <small class="float-right">
        <span title="Likes" name="Likes" class= "fa fa-thumbs-up" id="saveLikeDislike" data-type="like" data-post="{{ $team->id}}" class="mr-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary d-inline font-weight-bold">
            Like
            <span class="like-count">
                {{ $team->likes() }}
            </span>
        </span>
        <span title="Dislikes" class= "fa fa-thumbs-down" id="saveLikeDislike" data-type="dislike" data-post="{{ $team->id}}" data-toggle="lightbox" class="mr-2 btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger d-inline font-weight-bold">
            Dislike
            <span class="dislike-count">
                {{ $team->dislikes() }}
            </span>
        </span> 
    </small>
```

**JQuery Ajax code**

```
    <script>
        // Save Like Or Dislike
        $(document).on('click','#saveLikeDislike',function() {
            var _post=$(this).data('post');
            var _type=$(this).data('type');
            var vm=$(this);
            // Run Ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: site_url + "/save-likedislike",
                type:"post",
                dataType:'json',
                data:{
                    post:_post,
                    type:_type,
                    _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                beforeSend:function() {
                    vm.addClass('disabled');
                },
                success:function(res) {
                    // if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(res.success.attached)){
                    //     $("#"+_type+"-count").html();
                    //     var _inCount = _prevCount+1;
                    //     $("#"+_type+"-count").html(_inCount);
                    // }
                    if(res.bool==true) {
                        vm.removeClass('disabled').addClass('active');
                        vm.removeAttr('id');
                        var _prevCount=$("."+_type+"-count").html();
                        _prevCount++;
                        $("."+_type+"-count").html(_prevCount).load();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        // End
    </script>
```